# How to solve binding error for RibbonApplicationMenu

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon, ribboncontrolslibrary

Here is xaml:

```
<r:RibbonWindow x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window2"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:r="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=RibbonControlsLibrary"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.ViewModel"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:RibbonItem}">
            <r:RibbonButton Label="{Binding Label}" SmallImageSource="{Binding ImageUri}" Command="{Binding Command}" />
        </DataTemplate>

    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel>

        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <local:EmployeeViewModel x:Key="EmpoyeeViewModel"/>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <StackPanel.DataContext>
            <Binding Source="{StaticResource EmpoyeeViewModel}"/>
        </StackPanel.DataContext>

        <r:Ribbon Name="ribbon" >

            <r:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
                <r:RibbonApplicationMenu 
                ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems, Mode=OneWay}"
                Margin="0, 5, 0, 0"
                SmallImageSource="{Binding ImageUri}">
                </r:RibbonApplicationMenu>
            </r:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>

            <r:RibbonTab Header="Home">
                <r:RibbonGroup x:Name="Clipboard" ItemsSource ="{Binding MenuItems, Mode=OneWay}" >

                    <r:RibbonGroup.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <r:RibbonButton Label="{Binding Label}" 
                                                SmallImageSource="{Binding ImageUri}" Command="{Binding Command}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </r:RibbonGroup.ItemTemplate>

                </r:RibbonGroup>
            </r:RibbonTab>

        </r:Ribbon>

    </StackPanel>
    </r:RibbonWindow>
```

View Model:

```
public class EmployeeViewModel : BaseModel
{
    private RelayCommand _SaveCommand;
    private RelayCommand _NewCommand;

    public EmployeeViewModel()
    {
        LoadMenus();
    }

    public ICommand SaveCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _SaveCommand ?? (_SaveCommand = new RelayCommand(param => Save(), param => CanSave));
        }
    }

    public ICommand NewCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _NewCommand ?? (_NewCommand = new RelayCommand(param => New())); ;
        }
    }

    public bool CanSave
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    private void Save() { }

    private void New() { }

    ObservableCollection<RibbonItem> _MenuItems;

    public ObservableCollection<RibbonItem> MenuItems
    {
        get { return _MenuItems; }
    }

    private void LoadMenus()
    {
        _MenuItems = new ObservableCollection<RibbonItem>();

        _MenuItems.Add(new RibbonItem("New", "new-icon.png", NewCommand));
        _MenuItems.Add(new RibbonItem("Save", "save-icon.png", SaveCommand));
    }
}

public class RibbonItem
{
    public RibbonItem(string label, string imageUri, ICommand command)
    {
        Label = label;
        ImageUri = imageUri;
        Command = command;
    }

    public string Label { get; private set; }

    public string ImageUri { get; private set; }

    public ICommand Command { get; private set; }
}
```

Binding Errors:

> > System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'ImageUri' property not found on 'object' ''EmployeeViewModel' (HashCode=41834681)'. BindingExpression:Path=ImageUri; DataItem='EmployeeViewModel' (HashCode=41834681); target element is 'RibbonApplicationMenu' (Name=''); target property is 'SmallImageSource' (type 'ImageSource')
> >
> > System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'IsDropDownOpen' property not found on 'object' ''RibbonContentPresenter' (Name='PART_ContentPresenter')'. BindingExpression:Path=IsDropDownOpen; DataItem='RibbonContentPresenter' (Name='PART_ContentPresenter'); target element is 'RibbonButton' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')

What is I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs when either DataContext is wrong or if it is not set at all.

According to the error "SmallImageSource" is of type "ImageSource" and ImageSource should not be binded to a string. It should be a Uri.

Also for the next error

1.target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')

2. target element is 'RibbionButton' (Name='');
3. BindingExpression:Path=IsDropDownOpen;
4. DataItem='RibbonContentPresenter';
5. 'IsDropDownOpen' property not found on 'object' ''RibbonContentPresenter'  (Name='PART_ContentPresenter')'.
6. BindingExpression path error:
7. System.Windows.Data Error: 40 :

1 tells you that there is a NoTarget property causing the error

2 tells you that the NoTarget property is on a RibbionButton element

3 tells you the binding express causing the problem is {Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen}

4 tells you the DataItem/DataContext behind the RibbonContentPresenter element is an item of data type Char

5 tells you the actual problem with this: there is no property named IsDropDownOpen on the object of type RibbonContentPresenter

6 just tells you it's a binding error

Reading the error in correct sequence may help you. As there is nothing mentioned in the code snippet about this IsDropDownOpen , please edit your code.

Comment: Yes, first binding issue now solved. But second one is I am unable to figure it out. Look like it is in `RibbonControlLibrary`

Comment: `IsDropDownOpen` is property of `Ribbon`

Comment: What is the type of that property?

Comment: Can you edit your code which has IsDropDownOpen  binded and its property from code

Comment: It is in default [`RibbonControlsLibrary`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RibbonControlsLibrary)

Comment: You are not using it anywhere? I want the code where you are using it in your application

Answer (score 1):

The Ribbon's `DataContext` is the `EmployeeViewModel` and the `RibbonApplicationMenu` binds to `ImageUri` property, which does not exist in `EmployeeViewModel`

```
<r:RibbonApplicationMenu 
       ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems, Mode=OneWay}"
       Margin="0, 5, 0, 0"
       SmallImageSource="{Binding ImageUri}">
</r:RibbonApplicationMenu>
```

Comment: Yes, first binding issue now solved. But second one is I am unable to figure it out. Look like it is in `RibbonControlLibrary`